# How to use sugar.js in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sugar.js

http://sugarjs.com/

It's a libary so I can load it in browser directly. It's also a npm package, but how can I use it as a moudule?

In browser, load a js file will change the objects easily, but is not the same while working in nodejs, and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>Sugar isn't used as a standard CommonJS module, as the entire point of the library is to modify built-in prototypes. One you require it into your project, all the built-in objects will be extended and you can use them from there.</strike>

Edit: This is now no longer true as of v2.0.0. Prototype modification is now opt-in so you can use Sugar just like any other node module using the exported object. For more, see https://sugarjs.com/quickstart/

Answer (score 28):

You just install the module:

```
npm install sugar
```

then use it just like the API says:

```
var http = require('http');
var sugar = require('sugar');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.end('hey_there_good-lookin'.camelize());

}).listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Comment: Is there any point in assigning the return value of `require('sugar')` to a variable?

Comment: @callum Nope `require('sugar')` returns an empty object. Writing the `var sugar = ` part is useless.

Comment: Note this is not the case anymore as of v2.0.0. The exported object is now equivalent to the `Sugar` global object in the browser. This object allows calling functions statically, creating chaned objects, or extending natives (as before). For previous behavior, simply call `Sugar.extend()`. Note however that the api has changed as well. For more, see the [docs](https://sugarjs.com/docs/)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use sugar.js - it modifies native prototypes so EVERYTHING will use them - not just your module. Doing this is incredibly insidious, its not modular, and it will bite you in the ass when you least expect it.

Its worth saying it again: don't use any module that modifies native prototypes outside the (very reasonable) context of polyfilling. Don't use Sugar.js. Espcially in node.js - there's a module system there for a reason. I have personally run into awful issues with things that modify native prototypes. Weird things can happen deep in the bowels of your code.

Here's some more information on why modifying native objects is bad:

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/

UPDATE: It sounds like Sugar v2.0.0 now treats extending natives as opt-in, which is much better (since natives aren't extended by default).

Comment: B T, these are old - and mostly valid - arguments against modifying host objects in the browser and native prototypes. The developer of Sugar is very much aware of these issues, and Sugar is designed with safety against them in mind. http://sugarjs.com/native

Comment: That being said, I would say using sugar.js in a library is still inadvisable. But I see no reason to not use it in applications, and in fact my team has been using it on large, frequently-modified applications for several years to great effect. So far we've encountered exactly one issue, and it was obvious and simple to resolve (it was caused by a then-three-year-old version of Sugar, we just had to update it.)

Comment: Even if you're using it only in your applications, its very possible (might I say likely?) that it'll interact poorly with some random code that *you* wrote or some random code that you imported. I would literally never condone sugar.js - i've run into problems with it multiple times, which is why i wrote this answer in the first place. The developer of sugar is definitely so aware of the issue that he dedicated a whole space on the site for quelling the rabble. Unfortunately you *cannot* make sugar.js safe. The API is simply not safe in javascript - not to say it might be in other languages

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I like the API, its cool to have those features and it can make your code more readable and easier to write in the first place. Unfortunately it is not worth the *hours* of head scratching when something goes horribly wrong with native prototypes.

Comment: B T, I would like to know more about the issues you've had with sugar.js. As I said, I use it in a lot of applications, and I would like to learn from your experience with it.

Comment: I had issues with it a looong time ago. I can't remember what module had issues with it, but I spend hours looking into the issue, only to discover some inner module I had used had a bad interaction with the way that Array was modified. To solve that issue I tore out sugar.js and stopped using it. I also had issues with marak's colors.js which i put in some effort to solve there. This is the same reason people avoid using global variables these days. Standard global variables are ok cause everyone knows about them. Non standard global variables are bound to run into namespace collisions etc

Comment: Hi, creator of Sugar here. I've been waiting for nearly a year to answer this question as a big change was in the works. As of v2.0.0, extension of natives is now opt-in instead of default, and there are 2 new ways of calling methods. Sugar was originally never intended for libraries or any form of middleware, and you're absolutely right that using it for this was insidious. This was the exact reason for this change. For more about new usage, see [here](https://sugarjs.com/quickstart/).

Comment: @Andrew Glad to hear sugar's pulling out the monkeypatching!